# Splitting DataFrame based on index

Tags: python-3.x

I have a DataFrame which I want to split into three DataFrames based on the string properties of the index. The index consists of IDs with the first two letters indicating the country, e.g.

```
DE1
UK4
US5
DE2
UK1
US3
```

I want three DataFrames with indexes being:

```
DE1
DE2

UK1
UK4

US3
US5
```

This seems promising:

```
df.groupby(df.index.str[:2]).groups
```

But I don't know how to use it to solve my problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
split = []
for value in df.index.str[:2].unique().values:
    split.append(df[df.index.str[:2] == value])
```

We first compute the unique country code using the first 2 letters in the data frame. Then we loop over them and index into the data frame using all the unique country code. Here, I just added the resulting DataFrame to an array.